# Can one source code be deployed to Openshift, Heroku and Google App Engine at once?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, heroku, openshift

As subject, is is possible with just one source code, we can deploy our code to Openshift or Google App Engine? Heroku is not necessarily in my case.

My application is using Python Flask + PostgreSQL 9.1. I love the easiness in Openshift when I configure my technology stack, but is the case will be same with GAE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I work on Openshift and at this time I'm not aware of anything that will deploy your code to GAE and Openshift at the same time.

You might be able to write your own script for it.

Comment: Yeah, kind of. I am thinking the same way too. I haven't know much about GAE currently

Comment: I opted this as the answer, although I know that actually I am asking in the state that I know very little about GAE. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL is not available on GAE, so this code will definitely not run there.

Comment: I am completely new to GAE.. after several google, there is issue of vendor lock-in in GAE. I guess it's not going to be as easy as handling Openshift's Gear...